# Embedding FirefoxDriver into a JFrame

Tags: java, selenium

I'm using selenium with java and was wondering if there way anyway to embed the window, that is created by selenium, into a JFrame.

So instead of a new instance of the browser being created (which is annoying when you need to constantly open and close a FireFox driver) it would open and close inside of a JFrame which would be minimized.

Comment: I don't think that this can be done without extreme difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to me like a huge overkill (it would pretty difficult to develop such a thing) so I think what you want is some kind of continuous integration server which wil automate the testing for you (like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) or [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/), both have support for Selenium). Or you can try headless driver with either [PhantomJS](https://www.google.cz/search?q=headless%20selenium%20phantomjs&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&gws_rd=cr&ei=2T-JUuqiLIjF7AbAgYHQDA) or [HtmlUnit](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/HtmlUnitDriver).

Comment: Is there any other way to hide the FireFox driver (I have to use that for certain methods that aren't in HtmlUnit).